# How to configure ssis depending on another process?

Tags: sql, ssis

I have a ssis package that I am currently running at the same time. But now I need to run it only after a certain process. For example: After an extract that sometimes lasts 3 hours and sometimes 5 hours and sometimes it doesn’t start. The main question is how to bind the ssis package to this process. Note: There is a table that shows when the extract ends.

Comment: What is the process? How do you know when it completes?

Comment: Chain the steps together in a SQL Agent job.

Comment: Yes i have table which containing data when extract is completing.But i can not bind ssis package to this table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a new SSIS package with two steps:

Execute SQL task to check if data load is complete. Store the output in a variable (0 for not complete and 1 for complete).

Then conditionally connect the task to your current package if variable = 1. If variable = 0, end.

Comment: Thank you very much my friend.I am very grateful to you.

Comment: @Mehman967 why not accepting this answer. click on the mark on the left side of it since it solved the issue